# htmlentities fails in converting HTML entities to characters

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to convert the Convert HTML entities to their corresponding characters

i have an url

```
http://example.com?keyword=signs®ion_name%5B%5D=REG0502
```

It should be like this

```
http://example.com?keyword=signs&region_name%5B%5D=REG0502
```

after using htmlentities()

i tried the function htmlentities() in php 5.6,7.1,7.5 it works but in 5.5.38 it fails. What is the problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `urlencode()` for urls?

Comment: Can You convert the url i desired?

Comment: `echo str_replace('®', '&', 'http://example.com?keyword=signs®ion_name%5B%5D=REG0502');` ... all set?  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/488184eccb0c1ce55fa8fcf389e023506875df4a)  What is that in HTML `&donut;` ... lol  :-D  I'm getting old and can't see stuff that small....

Comment: its not only about '®'.
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html#named-character-references

Comment: Why is it there to begin with is the question.

Comment: it is because the htmlentities() is not converting HTML entities to corresponding characters.Even i could do what you suggest.

Comment: well `htmlentities` would convert it to `&copy;` and you dont really want that in your url do you?  Works for me [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/718f96c0d345ce6a910ea308d95f95f9402aee4e) and it's not copy, its `&reg;` whatever that is.  In anycase your URL is still broken.

Comment: the function htmlentities() would convert '®' to &reg; which i want bot this function is not working in hp 5.5.38

Comment: Why would you want `&reg;` in your query string?

Comment: Its working in sandbox but not on my server. I am not getting what is the problem.

Comment: You probably have non UTF8 stuff in there, when you copy and past it sometimes that will fix the charset issues.  You better off figuring how it happened and fixing that then trying to fix it later.  Even if you get `htmlentities` to work you still have to deal with the `;`